# Trust to trustworthy is like Fired to ___worthy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word. An example sentence would be:

> Yesterday I did something at work that is _______!

Comment: Can you fix your analogy? I don't see the parallelism in single words. Do you mean 'trusted'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seams like your comment is better suited for http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/ As it provides no feedback of any kind, on topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Close it if you so desire. I'm using the correct tag, with the correct question body. The answer that has the green tick is an existent word from the "lexicon" and suits my needs. I got what I asked for. You have some problem with such questions, as I said direct them to meta don't pour your anger or whatever it is that drives you, on my question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I never asked for non existent words. Being on this specific sites implies that any suggested words would be established words that can be found in he dictionary in your shelf. As a person whose mother tongue is nowhere near English (take a look at my screen name) I needed the help of this community. Aggressiveness like yours will decrease the reputation of this site much more than my question ever could!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is, I formed and asked my question exactly as I wanted and needed to. Your edit rewrote my question (and also note AFTER I've selected an answer) entirely and not recognisably. As it happens where I visit more frequently, questions that aren't well asked even with a correct tag get closed very quickly. Mine wasn't so the problem you're having is not well defined within the rules. Therefore I will not allow my question to be part of some imaginary rules a cited user (I assume), I've never heard of before, has. Your problem, as stated above, is much better suited for meta.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Going on one-by-one basis will not help anyone, so you'll have to fight the good fight again the next time around someone pops in.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Reverted back to your edit. Can we close this discussion now with my apologises (though mt motives stand and meta is still a good idea to go to, fur future references) ?

Comment: A totally acceptable question now. Thank you. Now my problem is that the suggestion 'sackworthy', which I can't find listed in any dictionary (and only in a few places on the internet, with, for the spelling variants, the intended meanings (a) dismissable (b) beddable (c) susceptible to pillage, has been given and accepted.

Comment: I've tried my best here. I was not really aware of rules prohibiting informal words as answers. You should unaccept my answer, and use whatever word you need in your work, yet accept the correct answer on this site regardless of whether you use it or not, just for sake of contribution to the community.

Comment: @loa_in_ I'm perfectly happy with the accepted answer! As far as I know "the asker" > "anyone else who might have similar problem" is a fairly high rule in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking from answer by @SGR I'd say the word is **sackworthy**.

A quick Google search for [*"sackworthy" work*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sackworthy%22%20work) shown that this word is in use in context you seem to intend.

It seems a nice sounding and informative word with no undesirable connotations.

Please note though, that this word is informal and does not figure in dictionaries I searched through.

Where it is used (rarely) on the internet, this word carries alternative stated senses *beddable* and *prone to pillage* (thanks @edwin-ashworth): it may perhaps be considered unsuitable for these reasons.

Comment: I've tried my best here. I was not really aware of rules prohibiting informal words as answers. Poster should unaccept my answer, and use whatever word he needs in your work, yet accept the correct answer on this site regardless of whether he uses it or not, just for sake of contribution to the community.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment. I intend to edit my answer now.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [**fireable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fireable), but it sounds a little awkward when used in your exact sentence. Changing it to something like 'Yesterday I did something fireable at work' would sound more natural.

> Designating an offence that, if committed, could result in the perpetrator being dismissed from his or her job.

*oxforddictionaries.com*

Or, if you'd prefer something a bit more informal, you could use [**sackable**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sackable)

> of or denoting an offence, infraction of rules, etc, that is sufficently serious to warrant dismissal from an employment

*Collins Dictionary*

Comment: I'm not sure *sackable* is more informal.  It's more common.

Comment: @ChrisH Both *fire* and *sack* are informal; the formal term is *dismiss*.

Comment: michael.hor257k - I agree; the official term for what the OP describes is *dismissable offence*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's true; It's the *more* informal I disagreed with (i.e. I claim they're equal in formality)

Comment: The use of "sack" to mean to terminate someone from employment is not used in the US. So sackable probably won't be understood by Americans.

Comment: @Andrew I've certainly hear "sack" used in the U.S. to mean fire.  Maybe there's a difference between regions in the U.S.; I live in Michigan.

Comment: @AndreasBlass oops, perhaps you are right that it is regional. I live in California.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I've heard *sack* in the US, but I've always thought of it as slangy (whereas *fire* is the default term).

Comment: @ruakh I agree; "sack" is more colloquial than "fire", which is in turn more colloquial than "dismiss" or "terminate someone's employment".

Answer (score 2):

A "sackable" offence?

**sacking** (n): the termination of someone's employment (leaving them free to depart)
Synonyms:
discharge, dismissal, dismission, firing, liberation, release, sack
Type of:
conclusion, ending, termination

> ‘On January 20, 100 employees at the company walked off the job over the sacking of 19 workers a week earlier.’
>
> ‘The mass sackings led to sympathy action by 1,000 British Airways ground staff and the halting of all BA flights at Heathrow Airport for more than 24 hours.’

Answer (score 2):

I like some of the other answers here better, but I believe the most accurate word would be "terminable".  As in "This action is a terminable offense, do you really wish to proceed?"

https://www.google.com/search?q=terminable

Perhaps something along the lines of "termination-worthy"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could coin the term **pink slip-worthy** and most readers would be able to get your meaning. Pink slip meaning:

> a notice from an employer that a recipient's employment is being terminated

*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary*

Comment: That's presumably an American usage.

Comment: @ChrisH I guess so too because in the UK at least it's known as a P45 and isn't pink IIRC

Comment: There isn't a literal pink slip/piece of paper in the US either.

Comment: @MD-Tech yes, I commented about "P45-able" regarding it as too localised for an answer

Comment: @MD-Tech, Not to mention, pink slip can refer to the title of a car... which also isn't pink! Gotta love this language we try and speak!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SGR (though I cannot comment on his, not enough reputation) that "*fireable*" is the correct word, *and* that it sounds weird in your example sentence.

However, "**sackworthy**" seems too informal for some situations ([Oxford agrees](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sack)).

To make "*fireable*" work with your example, I would suggest altering the sentence to @SRG's

> "Yesterday I did something fireable at work",

or alter it to be

> "Yesterday I did something at work that was a **fireable offence**!"

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey oh god... I feel dirty... :( thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a true parallelism, then the only correct answer is the word "fired" or "firedworthy".

From a logical problem-solving stand-point, 'Trust' and 'Fired' don't relate in a comparative context if the word which follows 'Trust' is 'trustworthy'. So, it must be a parallelism of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use ***fireworthy***, and I'd understand what you meant from the context. It's informal and rare.

*Fireworthy* — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fireworthy)

> *adjective* 3. (workplace or employment) Worthy of being fired (from a job).
>
> *"I can see no such difference and thus conclude—since Creed, Michael, and Jan are all equally blameworthy for a fire-worthy incident—they should all be fired."* — 2011, J. Jeremy Wisnewski, The Office and Philosophy: Scenes from the Unexamined Life

> *Yesterday I did something at work that is fireworthy.*